# converting inform7 table to javascript

Tags: javascript, inform7

I am trying to port an interactive fiction game from inform7 to javascript. A lot of the syntax is easily converted into javascript; some of it can even be optimized after conversion. But the 'Table' feature does not exist natively in javascript, and I can think of many ways to mimic it. This is what the syntax for an inform7 table looks like:

```
Table of example table
column one    column two    column three    column four
----------    ----------    ------------    ----------
----------    ----------    ------------    ---------

When Play begins:
    Choose a blank row from Table of example table;
    now column one entry is "text";
    now column two entry is 400;
    now column three entry is true
    now column four entry is [non primitive]
```

What is the most efficient way to implement this in javascript?

Please keep in mind that I plan on using strict mode, and do not want to even consider the use of 3rd party frameworks/libraries such as JQuery. Only JavaScript as defined in the latest ECMAScript Specs.

Some of my ideas:

using a map:

```
const tables = new Map();

// to create table
tables.set("wandering monsters", [
    new Map([
        ["monster name","default"]
    ])
]);

//to get table entry
tables.get("wandering monsters")[0].get("monster name");
```

using a function:

```
function table(name, row, key, val, entrylist){
    var result;
    if (table.data == undefined){
        table.data = new Map();
    };
    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 1:
            result = table.data.get(name);
            break;
        case 2:
            table.data.set(name, []);
            result = table.data.get(name);
            break;
        case 3:
            result = table.data.get(name)[row].get(key);
            break;
        case 4:
             table.data.get(name)[row].set(key, val);
             result = table.data.get(name)[row].get(key);
             break;
        case 5:
            table.data.get(name)[row] = new Map(entrylist);
            result = table.data.get(name)[row];
            break;
        default:
            result = table.data;
    };
    return result;
}
```

im editing on mobile

Comment: An array of arrays is probably simplest.

Comment: i also have to get entries by name, within a row. it resembles the Map() object, but has indexes like an array. there are multiple tables in inform7 games, and they do not follow JavaScript naming conventions.

Comment: Then just have an array of objects. The column names become object keys.